# Ansible using {{ item }} with csvfile lookups

Tags: ansible

I am not able to fetch the value from the csv using lookup.

I have converted my xlsx file to csv using python script

```
XLS:
rpm group   gid username    uid group   zone    IP
bind-utils  xygroup 700 jijin   5001    700 google.com  8.8.8.8
bind    infra   701 pavan   5002    700     
    app 702 rakesh  5003    700     
    dba 703 vignesh 5004    700     
            rajesh  5005    700
```

Comment: when i try to use lookup command and try to select the col 1 & 2 to create group, i get error.

-
  name: creating groups in the dns server
  group: >
    name={{ lookup('csvfile', item + ' file=/tmp/dns.csv col=1 delimiter=,') }}
    gid={{ lookup('csvfile', item + ' file=/tmp/dns.csv col=2 delimiter=,') }}
  with_items: "{{ groups_out.stdout_lines }}"

Comment: this is my CSV file output.
CSV:
bind-utils,xyzgroup,700,jijin,5001,700,google.com,8.8.8.8
bind,infra,701,pavan,5002,700,,
,app,702,rakesh,5003,700,,
,dba,703,vignesh,5004,700,,
,,,rajesh,5005,700,,

Comment: TASK [dns : creating groups in the dns server] 
 [WARNING]: The value [] (type list) in a string field was converted to u'[]' (type string). If this does not look like what you expect,
quote the entire value to ensure it does not change.

failed: [dns_node1] (item=bind-utils,xyzgroup,700,jijin,5001,700,google.com,8.8.8.8) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "bind-utils,xyzgroup,700,jijin,5001,700,google.com,8.8.8.8", "msg": "argument gid is of type <type 'list'> and we were unable to convert to int: <type 'list'> cannot be converted to an int"}

Comment: Please edit your question to add necessary information. Adding information in comments is almost unreadable due to the missing formatting and limit space.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the quotes. The quotes should be before item not before file.
PLease try as bellow

```
- name: test
  group:
    name: "{{ lookup('csvfile', '{{item}} file=/tmp/dns.csv col=1 delimiter=,')}}"
    gid: "{{ lookup('csvfile', '{{item}} file=/tmp/dns.csv col=2 delimiter=,')}}"
  with_items: "{{ groups_out.stdout_lines }}"
```